# How to run a script and not wait for it in Perl?

Tags: perl, cross-platform, platform-independent

I have a system call in Perl that looks like this:

```
system('/path/to/utility >> /redirect/to/log file');
```

But this waits for `utility` to complete. I just want to trigger this and let the Perl script finish irrespective of whether the `utility` call finished or not.

**How can I do this?**

I tried changing the line to

```
system('/path/to/utility >> /redirect/to/log file &');
```

but this syntax still waits for the call to finish on Windows. I need to make it work on Linux as well as Windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if ($^O eq 'MSWin32') {
   system('start "" \\path\\to\\utility >> \\redirect\\to\\log_file');
} else {
   system('/path/to/utility >> /redirect/to/log_file &');
}
```

or

```
if ($^O eq 'MSWin32') {
   system(1, '\\path\\to\\utility >> \\redirect\\to\\log_file');
} else {
   system('/path/to/utility >> /redirect/to/log_file &');
}
```

Comment: @Lazer, oops, it's `system 1`, not `system -1`. (Documented in perlport.) Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You could try looking at the `fork` keyword, and launch your system command from the forked process. See the `perlipc` manpage for examples.

Comment: fork() is not necessarily available on Windows. By default UNIX calls are only available when Perl runs on a UNIX platform. You can build Perl with a compiler flag to "emulate" the fork() call on Windows, but who knows if the OPs Perl has been built that way?

Comment: I was initially hostile to Mecki's comment -- `fork` has been a part of every Windows build of Perl for years now. But some of the subtle differences between `fork` on Windows and Unix do have a bearing on the OP. A Perl script on Windows will not exit until all `fork`ed children have completed, which is not what the OP wants. The simple script `fork || sleep 5` will return instantaneously in Unix, but it will run for 5 seconds in Windows.

Comment: @Mecki, `fork` is available on Windows. It is emulated using threads. No compiler flag needed.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way on POSIX-like systems is in fact the one you already tried:

```
system('/path/to/utility >> /redirect/to/log_file &');
```

The easiest way to get a tool to execute in background on Windows is to use `start.exe` as a launch helper:

```
system('start /path/to/utility >> /redirect/to/log_file');
```

However, I don't know if it works to redirect the output to log file that way and I have no Windows system around this very moment for testing it.

Yes, that means you would need a code branch depending on current system, but other solutions may need one, too. If your Perl has `fork()` emulation, you can in fact use `fork()` on both systems (this is a bit more complicated, since you cannot redirect stdout to a logfile that easy, you first have to open it in Perl and make it stdout of the forked child before calling the new process). If your Windows Perl has no `fork()` emulation, you also need a code branch, since in that case you can use `fork()` only on UNIX and you'll need to use `Win32::Process::Create` with the `DETACHED_PROCESS` option on Windows.

But maybe you can first let us know if using start is already working for you. If it does not, maybe `start.exe` doesn't handle slashes. In that case you may have to use something like

```
C:\\path\\to\\utility
```

instead (double backslash is important! A single backslash has a special meaning in string literals; it's the escape character).

To find out if you are running on Windows or not, take a look at the variable `$OSNAME` or `$^OS`, it should say something like "MSWin32" on Windows.

Comment: Perl never translates `/` to `\ `. Windows accepts `/` as a directory separator. That's the OS itself. The shell and individual commands aren't necessary as flexible. Some only accept `/` when it's in a quote string.

Comment: I don't think there's any `start.exe` -- I think it's a builtin -- but I'm not at my Windows machine to check.

Comment: @ikegami: There is no such thing as "the OS itself"; there are a couple of system calls that accept `/` on Windows, but by far not all of them. I read somewhere (I think in an O'Reilly book) that Perl does translate it for some system calls that are know to not accept `/`, but this information might be wrong of course. I will update my reply.

Comment: @ikegami: And no, start is no build-in, it is an own executable binary like 'open' on OS X, at least it was up to Windows XP: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/265016 and it looks like it also still is in Vista: http://tinyurl.com/3mwbsml

Comment: "kernel", "API", "Win32", "Win API", "system calls" call it what you want, but it does exist, and it does accept `/`.

Comment: I just checked and there is no `start.exe` on WinXP or Win7. It is a builtin like `copy` and `dir`. Those linked pages made the same mistake you did.

Answer (score 2):

This common task has been abstracted into the CPAN module `Proc::Background`